# How to loop through a list of input range sliders in the DOM and capture values with an each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Below is a function intended to loop through a series of input sliders with a specific id attribute and capture their values. It does not work. Why oh' why?
Thank you.

**JS Fiddle Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/V93D4/1/

**HTML**

```
<button id='button'>save</button>

<input id="pitchInput_1" type='range'></input>

<input id="pitchInput_2" type='range'></input>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 $('#button').click(function(){

     $('input[id^="pitchInput_"]').each(function(){
           alert(this.id);
           alert($('input[id^="pitchInput_"]').val()); // Doesn't capture correct val of BOTH sliders. 

        });


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `val()` only gets the first.

```
var values = $('input[id^="pitchInput_"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
});
alert(values.join('\n'));
```

Here, `values` is an array of the sliders' values.

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to your code will do the trick for you.

```
<input id="pitchInput_1" type='range'></input>

<input id="pitchInput_2" type='range'></input>
```

Now each loop evaluates the correct value of sliders.

```
$('#button').click(function(){

 $('input[type="range"]').each(function(){
     alert(this.id);
     alert($(this).val()); 
  });
});
```

See the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/V93D4/4/) here.

In addition to this, you will get appropriate values by just modify this line.

```
alert($('input[id^="pitchInput_"]').val());
```

with this one.

```
alert($(this).val());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: why would you give them same name.... suppose they are in a form? Is a very poor concept. You are trying to use name where class should be used

Comment: i agree, but i gave same name because if they are radio buttons. I changed my response a bit though.

Comment: This answers the question technically better since I said specifically 'each loop' in the title, but for reasons I will not go into Paul Drapers answer actually works better for what I'm doing.